# How to keep alive without using GCM and Wakelock

Tags: android, android-service, google-cloud-messaging, android-networking

So i have an application that i am working on. This apps requires to keep alive so that can send keep-alive message to server.

If i do not use wake-lock or wifi-lock app cannot send ping message after around 20 mins or so.

`WifiManager.WifiLock
Allows an application to keep the Wi-Fi radio awake. Normally the Wi-Fi radio may turn off when the user has not used the device in a while. Acquiring a WifiLock will keep the radio on until the lock is released. Multiple applications may hold WifiLocks, and the radio will only be allowed to turn off when no WifiLocks are held in any application.`

Because if i use wake-lock the battery will drain so fast.

And i don't want to use GCM either because its not guaranteed.

Could you give me a suggestion !

Comment: Are you sure holding the WiFi lock results in the battery draining fast? I did some testing before making the decision to add ping support to my app, and I could hardly see the difference, it was like maybe 10% longer time before the device wanted recharging when not holding WiFi lock, like 3 days vs. 2 3/4 days.

Comment: @RenniePet To send ping, did your apps need to keep both wakelock and wifilock. Thats make my-app drains battery fast

Comment: Yes, if the connectionn is via WiFi it needs both WiFi lock and Wake lock. (If connection is via cellular network data connection only Wake lock is needed.) In my experience the thing that drains the battery most is the display, so as long as the display is allowed to turn off then the devices I've tested on can typically run almost 3 days even when holding WiFi lock and Wake lock, and sending and receiving pings every 30 seconds.

Comment: @RenniePet thank you. Maybe what i need is to release wifi-lock when device using mobile data. I will do some further testing ..

Comment: There are several battery use analysis apps on Google Play, maybe you should try one of them. Maybe it's some app you've forgotten about that is running in the background that is the problem. For example there was an app I had installed to synchronize Microsoft Outlook email to my phone, and I finally uninstalled it because it was draining the battery so much.